# Jquery ajax post, but asp.net page keeps reverting back to original

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

In a jQuery script on a aspx page I have made changes to the UI, these have been reflected in the dta variable that is being sent in the data stream to the codebehind (aspx.vb).  But I can't get them to stick.  The page keeps reverting back to its original form, even after a rebind of the control.

Here is my script:  I'm a jQuery beginner...

```js
function btnUpdate() {
    var dta = {};
    $('#sortable').each(function (i) {
        dta['sortable' + (i + 1)] = $(this).text();
    });

    var data_save = $('#Form1').serializeArray();
    data_save.push({ name: "sortable1", value: dta.sortable1});

    var frm = $('#Form1');
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        cache: false,
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: data_save,
        async: false //Tried both ways??
        // This success section was added later, on a suggestion, but still does not work.
        success: function (data_save) {
            $('.result').html(data_save)
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<asp:Button ID="btUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClientClick="btnUpdate();" />
```

The dta in the script above is gathering data from a ListView control. At the moment in the code behind I using the Pre_render, but I've tried Page_Load, Load_Complete, Init, and it doesn't seem to matter:

```vb
  Private Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    If Request.Form("sortable1") <> "" Then
        Dim Sortedlist As String = Request.Form("sortable1")
        ProcessSortChange(Sortedlist)
        BindStudentsRankList() 'This seems to be ignored after it executes.  Oh it has the right values
        'ddlMatches_SelectedIndexChanged(Me, New System.EventArgs())
    End If
End Sub
```

So the ProcessSortChange, is a routine that changes the DB.  This code is confirmed to be working.  The disconnect lies somewhere between the codebehind and updating the screen.  Here is the rest of the facade, or face code in question:

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListView ID="lvRankList" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder1">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <%#Eval("SiteCourseID")%>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%# Eval("Rotation")%>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%# Eval("PrimaryPreceptor")%>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%# Eval("ETCategoryName")%>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%#Eval("Rank")%>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="container">
          <ul id="sortable">
            <table class="blue_table" style="font-size: small; border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder1" />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    <asp:Button ID="btUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClientClick="btnUpdate();" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I click the 'btnUpdate' it hits the 1) Function in the script... 2) then hits the PreRender code in the codebehind... But the page reverts back to its original form after it completes the jquery Ajax post cycle.

Since I'm new to jQuery posting, it may be something I just need to tweak a bit.  Oh 1 more thing.  If I manually refresh the page, it will show the new correct changes that I requested.  Or if I step through the code, while it is executing it will also show that the code everything is accurate, it is just not displaying correctly in the end.

Comment: I have a similar problem with jquery on a simple webpage where I'm changing div content when an image is clicked. The content that was changed reverts back on completion of the script. I'm new with jquery as well, so no idea whats going on with it. Did you ever solve this?